# Argocd to override existing base chart values

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, k3s, argocd, vault

I was trying to deploy an application with helm on argocd , and this is my case .
I want to deploy vault using helm and
i use hashicorp's vault chart as base chart and overriding the values using sub-chart
And the base chart has conditions on creating services, PVC , etc..
The values are override on the argocd still the service exists even the condition is made false by boolean

**Chart.yml**

```html
apiVersion: v2
name: keycloak
type: application
version: 1.0.0
dependencies:
  - name: keycloak
    version: "9.7.3"
    repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
```

**Argocd.yml**

```html
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: vault
  namespace: vault
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    chart: vault
    repoURL: https://github.com/myrepo.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
  destination:
    server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
    namespace: kubeseal
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you are overriding values in your chart and This is more of helm rather than ArgoCD.
Considering the `Chart.yaml` as below and chart name being `infra` which also has `keycloak` as dependency subchart:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: infra
type: application
version: 1.0.0
dependencies:
  - name: keycloak
    version: "9.7.3"
    repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
```

Create a values file in the same directory as your `Chart.yaml` with following contents

```
keycloak:
  fullnameOverride: keycloak-1
```

here `keycloak:` key in the values file sets the values for the subchart of name `keycloak`
You can have multiple subchart values override like above in one values file.